# How to set the scroll bar for a listbox at runtime properly?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, listbox

I created a lsitbox this way:

```
HWND hLstBx = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Listbox", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL, 10, 10, 300, 500, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LSTBX, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(GWL_HINSTANCE, hWnd), NULL;


//SendMessage(hLstBx, LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT, (WPARAM)1000, 0);
```

- Above It creates successfully a horizontal scroll bar but what I want:

How to set the value at runtime depending on the item with the longest length?

Please don't say something like in MFC but only `win32`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no free lunch here, if you want to call `LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT` or `LB_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` you have to measure the text of each item yourself to figure out the correct pixel size.

Each time an item is added/deleted or the controls font is changed you need to measure each item. Select the controls font (`WM_GETFONT`) into a HDC and use [`GetTextExtentPoint32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938(v=vs.85).aspx) or `DrawText(..., DT_CALCRECT)` to measure the text. You probably also want to add some padding, `(2 * GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE))` perhaps and account for the vertical scrollbar (if it is visible). You can optimize this by using `LB_SETITEMDATA`/`LB_GETITEMDATA` to cache the widths so you only have to calculate the size of a new item when it is added.

Once you know the widths of all items you can set the extent to the largest item.

```
UINT CalcLBItemWidth(HWND hLB, LPCTSTR Text)
{
    RECT r;
    HDC hLBDC = GetDC(hLB);
    HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hLBDC);
    HFONT hFont = (HFONT) SendMessage(hLB, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
    HGDIOBJ hOrgFont = SelectObject(hDC, hFont);
    ZeroMemory(&r, sizeof(r));
    DrawText(hDC, Text, -1, &r, DT_CALCRECT|DT_SINGLELINE|DT_NOCLIP);
    SelectObject(hDC, hOrgFont);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    ReleaseDC(hLB, hLBDC);
    return (r.right - r.left) + (2 * GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE));
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HWND hLB = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTBOX, NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_HSCROLL|WS_VSCROLL|LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT|LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL, 10, 10, 200, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)666, g_hInst, NULL);
            static const LPCTSTR strings[] = { TEXT("Foo"), TEXT("Foo bar"), TEXT("Foo bar baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz") };
            UINT largest = 0;
            for (UINT i = 0; i < 33; ++i)
            {
                UINT temp = CalcLBItemWidth(hLB, strings[i%3]);
                if (temp > largest) largest = temp;
                SendMessage(hLB, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) strings[i%3]);
            }
            SendMessage(hLB, LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT, largest, 0);
        }
        break;
        ...
```

There is a [MFC example of this here](http://gipsysoft.com/articles/global_subclass/) that subclasses the control and does all of it for you but there is nothing MFC specific that prevents you from doing the same in plain win32...

Comment: Will you mind to add a so brief example please? thanx anyway

Comment: What are you having trouble with? A working example of this is more than a couple of lines of code...

Comment: It really works fine for me so I edited your answer so I can resize in `WM_COMMAND` if press a button `ADD ITEM` to add a text from an edit box to the listbox using your function. So lovely! really Appreciate it!!!

Comment: You don't need to edit the answer. You can adapt the example for usage in your own code but editing it here just makes it less general and might not fit everyone's needs. The question is about LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT and how to calculate the width, it's not a "adding a new item from textbox" question.

Comment: Ah! I meant with edit " adapt the example for usage in my code".